# How do I create a function which evaluates to 1 when x is close to an integer, otherwise f(x)=0?

Tags: function-construction

I want to create a function f which is 1 when x is around an integer, otherwise f(x) = 0. Let's say that "around" is 0.2, then f(0)=1, f(0.1)=1, f(0.2)=1, f(0.3)=0, f(0.4)=0... ...f(0.7)=0, f(0.8)=1, etc. Image representation:

[image]

Comment: `f[x_] := If[Abs[x - Round[x]] <= 0.2, 1, 0]`

Comment: `UnitStep[Cos[2 Pi x] - Cos[2 Pi 0.2]]` or `UnitStep[TriangleWave[x + 1/4] - TriangleWave[0.2 + 1/4]]` or `UnitStep@Mod[x + 0.2, 1, -0.6]`

Comment: With adjustable low and high thresholds: `Clear[g];
g[x_, low_, high_] := 
  Clip[SquareWave[x + low] - SquareWave[x - high], {0, 1}];
Plot[g[x, 0.1, 0.2], {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> None, 
 AspectRatio -> 3/10, ImageSize -> Large]`